# Sometimes visual studio lets me edit cshtml file while running, sometimes not

Tags: html, visual-studio

I'm confused with the behaviour of visual studio.  Sometimes when my program is running, it lets me edit cshtml files, but then it will just randomly stop letting me do that and refuse to delete something I want deleted.  Any way to make it allow cshtml file editing all the time?

Comment: [possibly helpful](http://forums.asp.net/post/5554074.aspx)

Comment: yeh 'edit and continue' is already enabled